# assigning '/*' to variable

Tags: linux, bash

```
line='/*'
echo $line
```

Will prints all the directories in `/`

I want to print as below.

```
/*
```

Answer (score 8):

Quote the variable:

```
echo "$line"
```

For a lengthy explanation of why this works the way it does, see [EXPANSION](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the answer:

```
echo "$line"
```

Comment: Solved by using the -e option echo -e  \/\*